# Fail to install npm packages if i keep the package-lock.json file, npm ERR! errno -4048 after type npm install

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm, vuetify.js

I have a project from git, and when i tried to install npm packages using `npm install`, i get npm different errors:

**and if i delete `package-lock.json`,the npm install the packages successfully,but with different versions,that caused exceptions and conflicts in the project **

**So,how i can run npm install without deleting the lock file to keeping the versions rules?**

i tried to clear the npm cach using `npm cach clear --force` and remove the node_modules but not solved the problem (it's run only if i delete the lock file).

```
PS K:\project\Inmaa> npm -v
6.14.7
PS K:\project\Inmaa> node -v
v12.18.3

PS K:\project\Inmaa> npm install
npm WARN tarball tarball data for core-js@3.6.5 (sha512-vZVEEwZoIsI+vPEuoF9Iqf5H7/M3eeQqWlQnYa8FSKKePuYTf5MWnxb5SDAzCa60b3JBRS5g9b+Dq7b1y/RCrA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @firebase/auth@0.14.7 (sha512-NTQY9luV70XUA6zGYOWloDSaOT+l0/R4u3W7ptqVCfZNc4DAt7euUkTbj7SDD14902sHF54j+tk5kmpEmMd0jA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.9.0 (sha512-UgqBv6bjq4fDb8uku9f+wcm1J7YxJ5nT7WO/jBr0cl0PLKb7t1O6RNR1kZbjgx2LQtsDI9hwoQVmn0yhXeQyow==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @babel/helper-validator-identifier@7.9.0 (sha512-6G8bQKjOh+of4PV/ThDm/rRqlU7+IGoJuofpagU5GlEl29Vv0RGqqt86ZGRV8ZuSOY3o+8yXl5y782SMcG7SHw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for vuelidate@0.7.5 (sha512-GAAG8QAFVp7BFeQlNaThpTbimq3+HypBPNwdkCkHZZeVaD5zmXXfhp357dcUJXHXTZjSln0PvP6wiwLZXkFTwg==) 
seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for vuex@3.1.3 (sha512-k8vZqNMSNMgKelVZAPYw5MNb2xWSmVgCKtYKAptvm9YtZiOXnRXFWu//Y9zQNORTrm3dNj1n/WaZZI26tIX6Mw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for vue2-google-maps@0.10.7 (sha512-y5aBJTAsfGvpsbfgPaeWU7o7QbOeINZKsP6SB9qrBe8U8EYBFO/bTWo3rcMq/NOtgT/XssV3Nwg/2u3no6jWbw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for vuetify-loader@1.4.3 (sha512-fS0wRil682Ebsj2as+eruBoMPKaQYDhu/fDAndnTItzSY4RK4LOEIsssVL4vD6QY8dvUgoGL84SUQ6vGr777CA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for vuetify@2.2.18 (sha512-RXN065xh5xKmTnEH6+1YFZWp67soOJPTIqqPNliSp9eE72Q7a5fmaV1xQsEVVaVA12+5Hvroo7NW7MP/APucGw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @firebase/logger@0.2.5 (sha512-qqw3m0tWs/qrg7axTZG/QZq24DIMdSY6dGoWuBn08ddq7+GLF5HiqkRj71XznYeUUbfRq5W9C/PSFnN4JxX+WA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'K:\project\Inmaa\node_modules\.staging\@babel\plugin-transform-for-of-344259c6\lib\index.js'  
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'K:\project\Inmaa\node_modules\.staging\@babel\plugin-transform-for-of-344259c6\lib\no-helper-implementation.js'
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path K:\project\Inmaa\node_modules\.staging\vuetify-loader-7878cddd\LICENSE.md
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'K:\project\Inmaa\node_modules\.staging\vuetify-loader-7878cddd\LICENSE.md'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'K:\project\Inmaa\node_modules\.staging\vuetify-loader-7878cddd\LICENSE.md'] {  
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'K:\project\Inmaa\node_modules\.staging\vuetify-loader-7878cddd\LICENSE.md'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!     path: 'K:\\project\\Inmaa\\node_modules\\.staging\\vuetify-loader-7878cddd\\LICENSE.md'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'K:\\project\\Inmaa\\node_modules\\.staging\\vuetify-loader-7878cddd\\LICENSE.md'
PS K:\project\Inmaa> npm install
npm WARN tarball tarball data for ssri@7.1.0 (sha512-77/WrDZUWocK0mvA5NTRQyveUf+wsrIc6vyrxpS8tVvYBcX215QbafrJR3KtkpskIzoFLqqNuuYQvxaMjXJ/0g==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path K:\project\Inmaa\node_modules\.staging\ssri-b04c905c\index.js
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'K:\project\Inmaa\node_modules\.staging\ssri-b04c905c\index.js'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'K:\project\Inmaa\node_modules\.staging\ssri-b04c905c\index.js'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'K:\project\Inmaa\node_modules\.staging\ssri-b04c905c\index.js'] {   
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!     path: 'K:\\project\\Inmaa\\node_modules\\.staging\\ssri-b04c905c\\index.js'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'K:\\project\\Inmaa\\node_modules\\.staging\\ssri-b04c905c\\index.js'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'K:\project\Inmaa\node_modules\.staging\moment-28f13bf5\src\lib\moment\moment.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'K:\project\Inmaa\node_modules\.staging\@babel\parser-6252c24b\lib\plugins\flow.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'K:\project\Inmaa\node_modules\.staging\moment-28f13bf5\min\moment.min.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'K:\project\Inmaa\node_modules\.staging\vuetify-loader-7878cddd\lib\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'K:\project\Inmaa\node_modules\.staging\vuetify-loader-7878cddd\lib\loader.js'
```

package.json:

```
  {
        "private": true,
        "scripts": {
            "postinstall": "npm run prod",
            "dev": "npm run development",
            "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
            "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
            "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
            "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
            "prod": "npm run production",
            "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "axios": "^0.19.2",
            "cross-env": "^7.0",
            "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
            "fibers": "^4.0.2",
            "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
            "lodash": "^4.17.13",
            "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
            "sass": "^1.26.3",
            "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
            "vue": "^2.6.11",
            "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "@mdi/font": "^5.1.45",
            "@mdi/js": "^5.1.45",
            "firebase": "^7.15.3",
            "i": "^0.3.6",
            "moment": "^2.26.0",
            "promise": "^8.1.0",
            "vue-check-view": "^0.3.0",
            "vue-google-adsense": "^1.8.1",
            "vue-i18n": "^8.15.6",
            "vue-notification": "^1.3.20",
            "vue-router": "^3.1.6",
            "vue-script2": "^2.1.0",
            "vue2-google-maps": "^0.10.7",
            "vuelidate": "^0.7.5",
            "vuetify": "^2.2.18",
            "vuetify-loader": "^1.4.3",
            "vuex": "^3.1.3"
        }
    }
```

sample of package-lock.json:

```
{
    "requires": true,
    "lockfileVersion": 1,
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/code-frame": {
            "version": "7.8.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/code-frame/-/code-frame-7.8.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-a9gxpmdXtZEInkCSHUJDLHZVBgb1QS0jhss4cPP93EW7s+uC5bikET2twEF3KV+7rDblJcmNvTR7VJejqd2C2g==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/highlight": "^7.8.3"
            }
        },
        "@babel/compat-data": {
            "version": "7.9.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/compat-data/-/compat-data-7.9.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-zeFQrr+284Ekvd9e7KAX954LkapWiOmQtsfHirhxqfdlX6MEC32iRE+pqUGlYIBchdevaCwvzxWGSy/YBNI85g==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "browserslist": "^4.9.1",
                "invariant": "^2.2.4",
                "semver": "^5.5.0"
            }
        },
        "@babel/core": {
            "version": "7.9.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/core/-/core-7.9.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-kWc7L0fw1xwvI0zi8OKVBuxRVefwGOrKSQMvrQ3dW+bIIavBY3/NpXmpjMy7bQnLgwgzWQZ8TlM57YHpHNHz4w==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/code-frame": "^7.8.3",
                "@babel/generator": "^7.9.0",
                "@babel/helper-module-transforms": "^7.9.0",
                "@babel/helpers": "^7.9.0",
                "@babel/parser": "^7.9.0",
                "@babel/template": "^7.8.6",
                "@babel/traverse": "^7.9.0",
                "@babel/types": "^7.9.0",
                "convert-source-map": "^1.7.0",
                "debug": "^4.1.0",
                "gensync": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
                "json5": "^2.1.2",
                "lodash": "^4.17.13",
                "resolve": "^1.3.2",
                "semver": "^5.4.1",
                "source-map": "^0.5.0"
            },
            "dependencies": {
                "debug": {
                    "version": "4.1.1",
                    "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/-/debug-4.1.1.tgz",
                    "integrity": "sha512-pYAIzeRo8J6KPEaJ0VWOh5Pzkbw/RetuzehGM7QRRX5he4fPHx2rdKMB256ehJCkX+XRQm16eZLqLNS8RSZXZw==",
                    "dev": true,
                    "requires": {
                        "ms": "^2.1.1"
                    }
                },
                "ms": {
                    "version": "2.1.2",
                    "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/-/ms-2.1.2.tgz",
                    "integrity": "sha512-sGkPx+VjMtmA6MX27oA4FBFELFCZZ4S4XqeGOXCv68tT+jb3vk/RyaKWP0PTKyWtmLSM0b+adUTEvbs1PEaH2w==",
                    "dev": true
                }
            }
        },
        "@babel/generator": {
            "version": "7.9.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/generator/-/generator-7.9.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-onl4Oy46oGCzymOXtKMQpI7VXtCbTSHK1kqBydZ6AmzuNcacEVqGk9tZtAS+48IA9IstZcDCgIg8hQKnb7suRw==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/types": "^7.9.0",
                "jsesc": "^2.5.1",
                "lodash": "^4.17.13",
                "source-map": "^0.5.0"
            }
        },
        "@babel/helper-annotate-as-pure": {
            "version": "7.8.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-annotate-as-pure/-/helper-annotate-as-pure-7.8.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-6o+mJrZBxOoEX77Ezv9zwW7WV8DdluouRKNY/IR5u/YTMuKHgugHOzYWlYvYLpLA9nPsQCAAASpCIbjI9Mv+Uw==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/types": "^7.8.3"
            }
        },
        "@babel/helper-builder-binary-assignment-operator-visitor": {
            "version": "7.8.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-builder-binary-assignment-operator-visitor/-/helper-builder-binary-assignment-operator-visitor-7.8.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-5eFOm2SyFPK4Rh3XMMRDjN7lBH0orh3ss0g3rTYZnBQ+r6YPj7lgDyCvPphynHvUrobJmeMignBr6Acw9mAPlw==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/helper-explode-assignable-expression": "^7.8.3",
                "@babel/types": "^7.8.3"
            }
        },
        "@babel/helper-call-delegate": {
            "version": "7.8.7",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-call-delegate/-/helper-call-delegate-7.8.7.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-doAA5LAKhsFCR0LAFIf+r2RSMmC+m8f/oQ+URnUET/rWeEzC0yTRmAGyWkD4sSu3xwbS7MYQ2u+xlt1V5R56KQ==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/helper-hoist-variables": "^7.8.3",
                "@babel/traverse": "^7.8.3",
                "@babel/types": "^7.8.7"
            }
        },
        "@babel/helper-compilation-targets": {
            "version": "7.8.7",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/-/helper-compilation-targets-7.8.7.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-4mWm8DCK2LugIS+p1yArqvG1Pf162upsIsjE7cNBjez+NjliQpVhj20obE520nao0o14DaTnFJv+Fw5a0JpoUw==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/compat-data": "^7.8.6",
                "browserslist": "^4.9.1",
                "invariant": "^2.2.4",
                "levenary": "^1.1.1",
                "semver": "^5.5.0"
            }
        },
        "@babel/helper-create-regexp-features-plugin": {
            "version": "7.8.8",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-create-regexp-features-plugin/-/helper-create-regexp-features-plugin-7.8.8.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-LYVPdwkrQEiX9+1R29Ld/wTrmQu1SSKYnuOk3g0CkcZMA1p0gsNxJFj/3gBdaJ7Cg0Fnek5z0DsMULePP7Lrqg==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/helper-annotate-as-pure": "^7.8.3",
                "@babel/helper-regex": "^7.8.3",
                "regexpu-core": "^4.7.0"
            }
        },
        "@babel/helper-define-map": {
            "version": "7.8.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-define-map/-/helper-define-map-7.8.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-PoeBYtxoZGtct3md6xZOCWPcKuMuk3IHhgxsRRNtnNShebf4C8YonTSblsK4tvDbm+eJAw2HAPOfCr+Q/YRG/g==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/helper-function-name": "^7.8.3",
                "@babel/types": "^7.8.3",
                "lodash": "^4.17.13"
            }
        },
        "@babel/helper-explode-assignable-expression": {
            "version": "7.8.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-explode-assignable-expression/-/helper-explode-assignable-expression-7.8.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-N+8eW86/Kj147bO9G2uclsg5pwfs/fqqY5rwgIL7eTBklgXjcOJ3btzS5iM6AitJcftnY7pm2lGsrJVYLGjzIw==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/traverse": "^7.8.3",
                "@babel/types": "^7.8.3"
            }
        },
        "@babel/helper-function-name": {
            "version": "7.8.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-function-name/-/helper-function-name-7.8.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-BCxgX1BC2hD/oBlIFUgOCQDOPV8nSINxCwM3o93xP4P9Fq6aV5sgv2cOOITDMtCfQ+3PvHp3l689XZvAM9QyOA==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/helper-get-function-arity": "^7.8.3",
                "@babel/template": "^7.8.3",
                "@babel/types": "^7.8.3"
            }
        },
        "@babel/helper-get-function-arity": {
            "version": "7.8.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-get-function-arity/-/helper-get-function-arity-7.8.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-FVDR+Gd9iLjUMY1fzE2SR0IuaJToR4RkCDARVfsBBPSP53GEqSFjD8gNyxg246VUyc/ALRxFaAK8rVG7UT7xRA==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/types": "^7.8.3"
            }
        },
        "@babel/helper-hoist-variables": {
            "version": "7.8.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-hoist-variables/-/helper-hoist-variables-7.8.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-ky1JLOjcDUtSc+xkt0xhYff7Z6ILTAHKmZLHPxAhOP0Nd77O+3nCsd6uSVYur6nJnCI029CrNbYlc0LoPfAPQg==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/types": "^7.8.3"
            }
        },
        "@babel/helper-member-expression-to-functions": {
            "version": "7.8.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-member-expression-to-functions/-/helper-member-expression-to-functions-7.8.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-fO4Egq88utkQFjbPrSHGmGLFqmrshs11d46WI+WZDESt7Wu7wN2G2Iu+NMMZJFDOVRHAMIkB5SNh30NtwCA7RA==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/types": "^7.8.3"
            }
        },
        "@babel/helper-module-imports": {
            "version": "7.8.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-module-imports/-/helper-module-imports-7.8.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-R0Bx3jippsbAEtzkpZ/6FIiuzOURPcMjHp+Z6xPe6DtApDJx+w7UYyOLanZqO8+wKR9G10s/FmHXvxaMd9s6Kg==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/types": "^7.8.3"
            }
        },
        "@babel/helper-module-transforms": {
            "version": "7.9.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-module-transforms/-/helper-module-transforms-7.9.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-0FvKyu0gpPfIQ8EkxlrAydOWROdHpBmiCiRwLkUiBGhCUPRRbVD2/tm3sFr/c/GWFrQ/ffutGUAnx7V0FzT2wA==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/helper-module-imports": "^7.8.3",
                "@babel/helper-replace-supers": "^7.8.6",
                "@babel/helper-simple-access": "^7.8.3",
                "@babel/helper-split-export-declaration": "^7.8.3",
                "@babel/template": "^7.8.6",
                "@babel/types": "^7.9.0",
                "lodash": "^4.17.13"
            }
        },
        "@babel/helper-optimise-call-expression": {
            "version": "7.8.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-optimise-call-expression/-/helper-optimise-call-expression-7.8.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-Kag20n86cbO2AvHca6EJsvqAd82gc6VMGule4HwebwMlwkpXuVqrNRj6CkCV2sKxgi9MyAUnZVnZ6lJ1/vKhHQ==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/types": "^7.8.3"
            }
        },
        "@babel/helper-plugin-utils": {
            "version": "7.8.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/-/helper-plugin-utils-7.8.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-j+fq49Xds2smCUNYmEHF9kGNkhbet6yVIBp4e6oeQpH1RUs/Ir06xUKzDjDkGcaaokPiTNs2JBWHjaE4csUkZQ==",
            "dev": true
        },
        "@babel/helper-regex": {
            "version": "7.8.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-regex/-/helper-regex-7.8.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-BWt0QtYv/cg/NecOAZMdcn/waj/5P26DR4mVLXfFtDokSR6fyuG0Pj+e2FqtSME+MqED1khnSMulkmGl8qWiUQ==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "lodash": "^4.17.13"
            }
        },
        "@babel/helper-remap-async-to-generator": {
            "version": "7.8.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-remap-async-to-generator/-/helper-remap-async-to-generator-7.8.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-kgwDmw4fCg7AVgS4DukQR/roGp+jP+XluJE5hsRZwxCYGg+Rv9wSGErDWhlI90FODdYfd4xG4AQRiMDjjN0GzA==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/helper-annotate-as-pure": "^7.8.3",
                "@babel/helper-wrap-function": "^7.8.3",
                "@babel/template": "^7.8.3",
                "@babel/traverse": "^7.8.3",
                "@babel/types": "^7.8.3"
            }
        },
        "@babel/helper-replace-supers": {
            "version": "7.8.6",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-replace-supers/-/helper-replace-supers-7.8.6.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-PeMArdA4Sv/Wf4zXwBKPqVj7n9UF/xg6slNRtZW84FM7JpE1CbG8B612FyM4cxrf4fMAMGO0kR7voy1ForHHFA==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/helper-member-expression-to-functions": "^7.8.3",
                "@babel/helper-optimise-call-expression": "^7.8.3",
                "@babel/traverse": "^7.8.6",
                "@babel/types": "^7.8.6"
            }
        },
        "@babel/helper-simple-access": {
            "version": "7.8.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-simple-access/-/helper-simple-access-7.8.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-VNGUDjx5cCWg4vvCTR8qQ7YJYZ+HBjxOgXEl7ounz+4Sn7+LMD3CFrCTEU6/qXKbA2nKg21CwhhBzO0RpRbdCw==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/template": "^7.8.3",
                "@babel/types": "^7.8.3"
            }
        },
        "@babel/helper-split-export-declaration": {
            "version": "7.8.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-split-export-declaration/-/helper-split-export-declaration-7.8.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-3x3yOeyBhW851hroze7ElzdkeRXQYQbFIb7gLK1WQYsw2GWDay5gAJNw1sWJ0VFP6z5J1whqeXH/WCdCjZv6dA==",
            "dev": true,
            "requires": {
                "@babel/types": "^7.8.3"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try remove modules and install again.

1. `rm -rf node_modules`
2. `npm cache clean --force`
3. `npm install`

Comment: I tried many times,i get errors as long  i don't  delete the packge-lock.json file :(  @Warren Clarin

Comment: ahhh, try delete `package-lock.json` first.

Comment: yes dear,it works if i delete the file,but if i delete it,the npm will install the last versions of the packages right? that caused exception in compilation npm rum watch,the project work correctly at the owner,..sorry for my bad English :)  @Warren Clarin